# How to implement a 2D matrix version of wolfe line search?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

In [Wolfe line search](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eburke/crs/408/notes/nlp/line.pdf), the product of a gradient $g$ and the descend direction $g$ must be calculated. In 1D, both gradient and direction are vectors. Consequently, the product $ g^Td $ is a scalar. The objective function value is also a scalar number. The condition $f(x+\alpha d)<f(x)+\alpha cg^Td$ make sense. But in 2D situation, for example, an objective function using Frobenius norm
$$
F(X) = \frac{1}{2}||AXB^T-C ||^2_F
$$
has a 2D gradient $G(X)=A^T(AX-B)B$ and a 2D descend direction $D(X)=-G(X)/||G(X)||$. When using line search, $G(X)^TD(X)$ would produce a 2D matrix. While $ F(X+\alpha D)$ and $ F(X) $ are scalar. How to use the Wolfe condition in this situation? Are there any alterlatives?

Comment: Frobinous $\to$ Frobenius

Comment: Write it in a Vector Form?

Comment: There's a reason it's called a line search. The 2D version is not a "line" search. I have no idea whether there is a 2D analog of the Wolfe conditions or strong Wolfe conditions.

Comment: The Wolfe conditions do not apply. You'd have to develop the Chow conditions. Or maybe you can call them the 2D Wolfe conditions.

Comment: "Are there any alternatives?" Yes, use 1D line search o rtrust regions.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone In my situation, X is 1024*1024,and C 128*18000. Vectoerized G will be a large scale vector and the hessian matrix will out of memory in most PC. So the only way to solve this problem is to use a optimizing algorithm without hessian.  The steepest descend converges too slowly. That's why I want a 2D version of wolfe line search.

Comment: Try LBFGS .That is limited memory BFGS Quasi-Newton. It stores only a small number of gradients rather than the Hessian, so it requires much less memory than BFGS or Newton method, but works almost as welll as BFGS.You are destined for failure trying to create your own 2D "line" search.  Maybe you could do it if if your name were Wolde

Comment: But (L)BFGS(-B) just simplified the calculation/ approximation of the Hessian Matrix. It does not change the size of the matrix. If X is 1024*1024,Grad(X) will be 1024*1024 and "hessian" or approximated hessian tensor would be (1024*1024)*(1024*1024).  That's too large. @MarkL.Stone

Comment: No. LBFGS(B) never explicitly forms a Hessian (approximation) matrix. It retains the most recent m number of gradient vectors, where m is usually in the range of 5 to 20.. The algorithm performs operations on the retained gradients so that the results of operations with them are the same as would be obtained if a Hessian based only on the m most recent gradients were formed explicitly. That's the whole point of LFBGS, to reduce the memory requirement vs. BFGS for high dimensional problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS

Comment: @MarkL.Stone How to calculate $\rho_k$ and $H_k$ when $g_k$ is a 2D matrix? Any matrix version of L-BFGS-B available?

Comment: Generally, you have to stack the  columns of an $m$ by $n$ matrix optimization variable into a single vector of length $mn$, and calculate the gradient of this vector..An optimization modeling toolbox, such as YALMIP, can do this vec'ing, and calculation of the gradient, for you, i.e., you declare as many scalar, vector, and matrix optimization variables as you want, and it stacks them into one vector and calculates the gradient, calls the solver, then unstacks the solution back to your original variables. This is a very common paradigm. I have used it many times.

Comment: But when should I vectorize X? If at the beginning, a kronecker product would be involved to form $||Kx-b||$ where $K=kron(A,B)$. Here $K$ is too large for PCs. Is it OK to calculate $G(X)$ using a matrix-form and then directly vectorize $G(X)$?

Comment: You need to use the Inner Product of Matrices: $ \operatorname{Tr} \left( {X}^{T} Y \right) $ which matches $ \operatorname{Vec} \left( X \right)^{T} \operatorname{Vec} \left( Y \right) $.